# Grails all url or certain url restricts to member's login via intercepter or application yaml?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

Need some advice for restricting all url or certain url to redirect to login page. Currently plugins installed is spring security core. I was thinking of just applying intercepter's before() to do the redirection. Is there a default way from spring security core plugin?

Answer (score 3):

> Need some advice for restricting all url or certain url to redirect to
>   login page.

It wouldn't make sense to redirect all url to a login page but if you want to redirect certain urls to a login page you could do that easily with an interceptor.

The fact that you are redirecting to a login page and you mentioned spring security suggests that maybe you only want to redirect to login if the request comes from an unauthenticated user.  Spring security will do that for you automatically if you define restrictions either in the application's config and/or using the `@Secured` annotation.  There is a lot of information about that at https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/3.2.x/index.html#requestMappings.